# CSS class not applying style

Tags: html, css, django

In regard to the first CSS rule, it works when i use the 'p' tag by itself. When I apply the 'article' class with or without the 'p' tag, it doesn't work. Why is that? **Also the 'hr' tag with the class of 'one' works (which means CSS file is working).** This seems so basic. I don't understand why it isn't working. Any ideas?

> **HTML**

```
<p class=article>{{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}</p>
```

> **-- Also tried this**

```
<p class="article">{{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}</p>
```

> **external CSS file**

```
p.article { 
    color:red; 
}

hr.one {
    border:none;
    height: 2px;
    background: #cec4c4;
}
```

> **HTML Output**

```
<div>

        <h1 class=display-4><a href="/blog/2020/5/28/gdddsasddsg/">gdddsasddsg</a></h1>

        <h6><span class="font-italic font-weight-normal">By: </span>gdorman619&nbsp;&nbsp;<span
                class="font-italic font-weight-normal">Published Date: </span> May 28, 2020, 12:24 p.m.</h6>

        <p class="article"><p>sdadfsdsfdsfa</p></p>

        <hr class="one">

    </div>
```

[image: Place where blue arrows are pointing should have red text]

Comment: Either there is conflicting CSS or has something to do with the <p> content. Can you share the output HTML in a snippet to help figure it out? Might also help to try using the browser's dev tool to inspect the problematic area.

Comment: I actually just figured out it has something to do with the content inside the p tag. I put the word hello in and it worked. Any ideas why the django template tag is messing things up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you printing content from a WYSIWYG-editor or something else that is not a pure string? In that case, that content will likely enforce its own markup as inline HTML and external css is not going to work as inline CSS inside HTML has a higher specificity then CSS placed in an external stylesheet, unless you apply `!important` to the color, which makes me cringe on my behalf.

Comment: I actually just figured out it has something to do with the content inside the p tag. I put the word hello in and it worked. Any ideas why the django template tag is messing things up?

Comment: Within a CMS, in WYSIWYG-editors, you can set text colors, font sizes etc. and these changes will be applied inline in the HTML it prints, like e.g.  `style="color:black"`. Notice though that if you print text, the very content itself can be a `p` already, thus resulting in a `p` inside the `p` with the class 'article'

Comment: With that being said, is there something I can do within CSS to only apply to article class inside of p tag?

Comment: I actually don't know how the output in HTML looks like. Could you share a sample? Then it will become clear what will be best.

Comment: I added a picture to my main post. It's where the blue arrows are pointing.

Comment: I misread your comment. I think this is what you're looking for.

Comment: <p class="article"><p>sdadfsdsfdsfa</p></p>

Comment: It looks like you're right. There is another p tag inside article.

Comment: Yes, that is indeed I am looking for. In that case, `p.article` gets a color, but that color isn't inherited by the nested `p`, which has its own default settings. You now have two options:
 1. Adjust the CSS declaration to `.article p`. As nesting p's is not nice, I wouldn't recommend, but this should make it work, though.
 2. Replace the HTML with `<article><p> </p></article>` and apply `article p` as color, and (if that doesn't work, well, !important). `<article>` is a semantic tag. You can also use `<div class="article"> </div>`, that works fine, too, with `.article p`.

Comment: Okay option two worked.  I did this: <article class=post-content>{{ post.body|truncatewords:30|linebreaks }}</article>   and  article.post-content{ 
    color:red; 
}

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks mostly good. To add a class attribute, you must specify the name of the class with quotes, like this:

```
<p class="article"> Your code here</p>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Hello. I've done that and it still doesn't work. I tried single quotes too.

Comment: Did it end up helping with your final solution? Looked like you got it

Answer (score 0):

Try with this css.

```
.article { 
    color:red; 
}

.one {
    border:none;
    height: 2px;
    background: #cec4c4;
}
```

it may help you